# Asp.net use Url.Action methods in views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, action

In my application i need to call the **download method** inside **Home controller**. 
I used `@Url.Action` method but it shows error.

[image]

Comment: are you using MVC or Asp.net? @Url.Action() is MVC razor code.

Comment: i'am using mvc. trying play video from controller

Answer (score 1):

try with following `source` tag code.

```
<source src="@Url.Action('download', 'Home')" type="video/mp4" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It is my mistake. i am using MVC 2.But above code is correct for MVC 4.
In MVC 2 server side code should be placed within <%%> atg.

```
<source src="<%=@Url.Action("Download","Home") %>" type="video/mp4">
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use single enclosing tags outside and double quotes inside
for example

```
<source src='<%= Url.Action("Download","Home") %>' type='video/mp4'>
```